# How to center a fixed top Navbar in bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center a **fixed top navbar** in Bootstrap 4 apla 6 but it is not centering it, but instead fills the top in full. How can I make it centered while fixed at the top. I have placed the nav bar in a container as mentioned on the website but it is not centering.

Please see images below

Centered but not fixed at top
 [image: centered image]

fixed at top, but filling the width even though it is in a container
[image: top fixed]

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse ">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
   </div>
```

It seems if you wrap it in a div with container class  it does not work but if you use the container class in the nav bar it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the navbar a container too...

http://www.codeply.com/go/sJbrJciQia

```
<nav class="navbar container navbar-toggleable-sm fixed-top navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I see that the original answer here is the right one for the asked question - which works for when you want your navbar background to be 'contained/centered' too. 
However, if you want your navbar background to take full width, my way is the way to go.

---

Adding .container to the `<nav>` element will create a new problem: the `<nav>` background will stop occupying full width. Which is usually not the desired behavior.

To get around this, simply nest all the contents of the  element in a .container .As follows:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm fixed-top navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbar1">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```