# How to center a bootstrap 4 toolbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to center a toolbar horizontally. I found lot of different solutions but none seem to work in bootstrap 4.

This is the closest I get but it requires me to give a width. The toolbar places itself leftmost in the panel. The number of items in the toolbar might vary and thus the toolbar will never be really centered. How can I properly center a toolbar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 </head>

 <body class="bg-secondary">
  <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 300px; background:red">
   Centered element<br/>
   <div class="btn-toolbar mx-auto" role="toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">3</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Edit: this is not a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952368]. That question is about a *navbar*, not a toolbar, in a container. I have seen that question while searching but I don't see how it applies to the html presented.
[image]

Comment: Note: `<br>` does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: What have you tried that doesn't work? What about `text-align:center` on the containing element? Seems to work even without width…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center a fixed top Navbar in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952368/how-to-center-a-fixed-top-navbar-in-bootstrap-4)

Comment: @Rob I don't see how's that duplicate. Maybe to an experienced user but to me as a novice it seems completely different navbar<->toolbar.

Comment: @tobiv I tried that on the red div but apparently another extra div is needed as shown by ZimSystem, I didn't try that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways. You could make the toolbar display:inline-block (`d-inline-block`) and use **`text-center`** on the parent.

https://www.codeply.com/go/U3sXVBzDK4

```
   <div class="text-center">
      <div class="d-inline-block" style="background:red">
            Centered element<br/>
            <div class="btn-toolbar mx-auto" role="toolbar">
                <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">3</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Another way is using flexbox **`justify-content-center`** on the parent (d-flex)

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="btn-toolbar mx-auto" role="toolbar">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="First group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">3</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One other solution which may be more to your liking is simply adding `justify-content-center` to your `btn-toolbar` like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12" style="background:red">
    
        <div class="btn-toolbar justify-content-center" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
          <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">3</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">4</button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">5</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">6</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">7</button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">8</button>
        </div>
        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No need to rely on wrappers, or applying `inline-block` and having to concern yourself with unintended white space.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox to center them for example. Also your text would preferably be inside a p tag and not only a div tag.

```css
.mx-auto {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: center;
}

p {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="bg-secondary">
  <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 300px; background:red">
    <p>Centered element</p><br/>
    <div class="btn-toolbar mx-auto" role="toolbar">
      <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why change things around to use flex when a simple `margin: 0 auto;` will do it?

Comment: Oh yeah, definitely see your point. (been using a lot of flexbox lately so clearly that just came to mind straight away)